# index (of: element) does not exist

Tags: swift, indexof

I have a really strange error. Have been learning Swift and was reading the documentation on finding the index of an object in an array here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689674-index

However this method does not exist in my Xcode.

Here is an example:

```
var items : [TaskItem]
items = [TaskItem] () 

    let rowitem = TaskItem()
    rowitem.text = "helloworld"
    items.append(rowitem)

//Attempting to find the index of an object

   items.Index(of: rowitem)
```

//error - Xcode cannot find the specific func I am looking for

I have attached an image of the methods that appear and have not been able to find an answer for why this might happen anywhere.

I cannot find the use of the func index(of:)method although I know it exists!

I get the following compiler error:

> ChecklistViewController.swift:186:26: Argument labels '(of:, _:)' do
>   not match any available overloads
>
> ChecklistViewController.swift:186:26: Overloads for 'index' exist with
>   these partially matching parameter lists: (Int, offsetBy: Int),
>   (Self.Index, offsetBy: Self.IndexDistance)

[image]

Comment: Is that a typo in your post? It should be `items.index(of: rowitem)`. Note `index` instead of `Index`.

Comment: Is `TaskItem` `Equatable`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TaskItem` needs to conform to the `Equatable` protocol in order to use `index(of:)`.

Comment: In case of `class` just make sure the class inherits from `NSObject` - which is equatable.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally agree with Tim vermeulen but we can get the index of array using the  below code and its working perfectly.

```
class Name {

    var firstName:String  = String()
    var lastName:String = String()

    var fullName:String{
        return firstName+lastName
    }
}

var items:[Name] = [Name]()

    let rowitem = Name()

    let name:Name = Name()
    name.firstName = "Vala"
    name.lastName = "bbbb"

    items.append(rowitem)
    items.append(name)

//Attempting to find the index of an object
   print(items.index{$0 === name}!)
```